# design a method in java receives 2 D array and manipulates each column in it

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, calculated-columns

I am trying to design a method in java which receive 2 D array and manipulate each column in it. then, save this manipulation whereas each column will be represented as a one value in the return array. My problem is that, I do not know, how can I read every column individuall. Could you suggest me please.

```
int[] ibraMethod(int[][] InputArray){
    int[] Array_After_ibraMethod = new int[24]; 
    int APoints = 0;
    int BPoints = 0;
    int CPoints = 0;

    for(int h = 1; h < 24 ; h++){
        System.out.println("\n Hour"+ h);

    for(int i = 0; i<InputArray.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<InputArray[h].length; j++){
        if(InputArray[i][j]==1){
            APoints = APoints +3;
        }
        else if(InputArray[i][j]==-1){
            BPoints = BPoints +2;
        }
        else if(InputArray[i][j]==0){
            CPoints =  CPoints +1;
        }
        }

    }

    Array_After_ibraMethod[h] = Compare(APoints, BPoints, CPoints);
    }

    /// to print////
    System.out.println("\n After ibraMethod");

    for (Integer i :Array_After_ibraMethod) {
        System.out.print(i.intValue() + " ");
    }

    return Array_After_ibraMethod;


}
```

and this is the compare function code

```
 Compare(int a, int b, int c) {

    int r;

    if ((a > b) && (a > c)) {

        r = 1;
        System.out.println("\n A ");

    } else if ((b > a) && (b > c)) {

        r = -1;
        System.out.println("\n B ");

    } else {

        r = 0;
        System.out.println("\n C");

    }

    return r;

}
```

Comment: Hi ibra, do you want to print the result array "Array_After_ibraMethod" ? one column at a time?

Comment: Hi Lalit , Actually I want to apply the Compare function for each column and save the result as a one value in the Array_After_ibraMethod.

Comment: Ibrahem, can you please share the code for Compare()

Answer (score 0):

Use `j<InputArray[i].length;` instead of `j<InputArray[h].length;` **as** `j<InputArray[h].length;` may give you java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException